# paging in php to show 123....7 instead of 1234567?

Tags: php, pagination

well i have a class pagination

```
<?php
class Pagination {

  public $current_page;
  public $per_page;
  public $total_count;

  public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=20, $total_count=0){
    $this->current_page = (int)$page;
    $this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
    $this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
  }

  public function offset() {
    return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
  }

  public function total_pages() {
    return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
    }

  public function previous_page() {
    return $this->current_page - 1;
  }

  public function next_page() {
    return $this->current_page + 1;
  }

    public function has_previous_page() {
        return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
    }

    public function has_next_page() {
        return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
    }


}

?>
```

and here is how i use this in index.php

```
<?php

$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$per_page = 4;
$total_count = class::count_all();

$pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename ";
$sql .= "LIMIT {$per_page} ";
$sql .= "OFFSET {$pagination -> offset()}";

?>

<?php foreach($variables as $variable):
?>

<?php endforeach;?>

    <?php
    if ($pagination -> total_pages() > 1) {

        if ($pagination -> has_previous_page()) {
            echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=";
            echo $pagination -> previous_page();
            echo "\">&laquo; Previous</a> ";
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagination -> total_pages(); $i++) {
            if ($i == $page) {
                echo " <span class=\"selected\">{$i}</span> ";
            } else {
                echo " <a href=\"index.php?page={$i}\">{$i}</a> ";
            }
        }

        if ($pagination -> has_next_page()) {
            echo " <a href=\"index.php?page=";
            echo $pagination -> next_page();
            echo "\">Next &raquo;</a> ";
        }

    }
?>
```

my problem is if there are alot of pages i want it to out put 1 2 3 ....... 10
instead of  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Thanks in advance and i am really sorry for annoying all of you like this

Comment: What've you tried? I should think you could do `if ($pagination->total_pages() > 4) {` in your second script. Give it a go, we'll help!

Comment: There's no need to apologise for "annoying" people here - you can't be expected to know everything. But Stackers do like to see people having given things a good go first - mainly because it is the best way to learn `:)`

Comment: @halfer Thanks alot for your help i really appretiate it

Comment: No worries. Do try to write out some code next time if you can - and people will help you improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$delta = 1; // +/- 1 page from current
$start = max(1, $page - $delta);
$end = min($pagination -> total_pages(), $page + $delta);

if ($start > 1) {
    // place first page link
    echo " <a href=\"index.php?page=1\">1</a> "; 
    if ($start > 2) {
        // place "..." if $start is not next to "1"
        echo " ... ";
    }
}
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    if ($i == $page) {
        echo " <span class=\"selected\">{$i}</span> ";
    } else {
        echo " <a href=\"index.php?page={$i}\">{$i}</a> ";
    }
}
if ($end < $pagination -> total_pages()) {
    if ($end < $pagination -> total_pages() - 1) {
        // place "..." if $end is not prev to "1"
        echo " ... ";
    }
    // place last page link
    echo " <a href=\"index.php?page={$pagination -> total_pages()}\">{$pagination -> total_pages()}</a>"; 
}
```

This will generate:

```
1 2 3 ... 10
```

in case of 10 pages and "2" as current page, and

```
1 ... 3 4 5 ... 10
```

in case of "4" as current page, etc.